# PyQt for Beaglebone

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, beagleboneblack, apt

I am trying to develop a GUI application on a Beaglebone Black (BBB) using PyQt, but I don't know if it is necessary to install this application on the BBB or if I can do it using a remote application such as VMware (Ubuntu). I investigated and found out that PyQt is already installed on the latest Debian image for the BBB, so I tried to install this application by using the command line `sudo apt-get install PyQt4`, but I receive a message saying "this file was not found".

Is installing this program on the BBB the best option, or is it better doing it remotely with VMware? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-cache search pyqt4`

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-cache search PyQt4` to list all available packages related to PyQt and select the exact package(s) you want to install. You must install the basic package on the BBB board if you want your application to run on the BBB board directly. If your application is a web client (communicates with the BBB board by socket), you can install the application anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Install putty on your local machine, then you can SSH to the BBB using address 192.168.7.2 if you are powering it via USB from your system. And then start anything you want to do on BBB

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```